# Array consistency - basic C programming

Tags: c, string, numbers

I have a structure of strings (name surname address etc).

I need to make sure that the first string (the name) has no numbers in it. I've been trying different methods, but in vain. Any help? :/

By the way, I'm new here. Help much appreciated.

Comment: Write a method that works and use that. Write tests to drive your development.

Comment: what do you mean make sure it has no numbers in it?  do you mean that when you find that it has numbers in it, you somehow handle that error or do you mean that when the string is generated, there should be no numbers?

Comment: this also sounds like a problem that regexes can solve

Comment: What are some things you tried, and what happend when you tried them?

Comment: yes im trying to find a method that works thats basically my question XD.

Comment: for ex. the user enters the name Gian1, then the program detects the 1 and says that it is invalid. I tried this:

if (getchar() <=65 || getchar()>=122) then printf("error");

didnt work though.

Comment: @SamIam:  Then you have two problems. (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

RegEx seems like overkill for such a simple problem.

Comment: It would be clearer to say "digits" rather than "numbers".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `isdigit` function from `<ctype.h>`.

```
#include <ctype.h>

/* Return 1 if the name is valid, 0 otherwise. */
int check_surname(const char *name)
{
  for (int i = 0; name[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (isdigit((unsigned char)name[i]))
    {
      return 0;
    } 
  }
  return 1;
}
```

> **C11 (n1570), § 7.4.1.5 The `isdigit` function**
>   The `isdigit` function tests for any decimal-digit character (as defined in 5.2.1).
>
> **C11 (n1570), § 5.2.1 Character sets**
>   the 10 decimal digits:
>   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: Actually you should use `isdigit((unsigned char)name[i])`; if plain `char` is signed, the `is*()` functions can fail for negative `char` values.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Indeed. I forget it everytime.

Answer (score 0):

For checking whether a string doesn't contain any numerical (decimal) characters, you can write a function like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int has_numbers(const char *p)
{
    while (*p) {
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)*p)) {
            return 1;
        }
        p++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Repeating my comment on the other answer: Actually you should use `isdigit((unsigned char)name[i])`; if plain `char` is signed, the `is*()` functions can fail for negative char values

Comment: @KeithThompson Fair point, fixed it! Thanks.